# Is it safe to use data from a div id in a MYSQL statement?

Tags: jquery, mysql, html

I'm working on a very simple 1 tiered commenting system using `Jquery`/`Ajax`/`PHP`/`MYSQL`.  The page initially displays a main comment which users may post replies to.

```
<div id="com100">Parent Comment</div>
```

I was advised to use the parent comment's `div` id value, *com100*, as a *parent ID* in a `MYSQL` `INSERT` statement for each corresponding reply.

My question: is this safe?  Can't the `div's` id value be changed by any user?  Potentially inserting replies associated with the wrong comment, or worse?

Data is being validated and `bindParam` are being used.  I'm more concerned with replies being stored under the wrong parent comment.  Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, the `id` value can be changed by any user. At least, I can do that with Firebug on Firefox. So don't try it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main question, really is *how* that div ID is passed to the back end. Presumably, with the technology you're using, you're going to grab the ID using Javascript/jQuery and then send it to the server, using a standard POST request. In this case, it's the POST request that is vulnerable. Someone will be able to read your code, see how the data is POSTed to the server, and then fake the same call with a different ID.

Up to that point, on the client side, you're normally fine to rely on the IDs of the DIVs -- grab them without validation using your jQuery, assume they're the right, server-generated values, and so on. The validation of the ID should be done at the server end, after the POST has come in. Does the ID make sense? Does that comment exist? Is the authenticated user allowed to post a comment under that parent ID, etc.

So, don't worry about people changing the DIVs ID in the document, because that's just a complicated and unlikely way of doing what could be done with a faked POST request anyway. But *do* validate your data server-side, once the POST comes in.

Fundamentally, it doesn't matter how much validation you do on the client side, as an attacker doesn't have to *use* any of *your* code to fake a POST request. They just need to know the URL you're POSTing to and the names of the POST variables, which will always be easily available to them through reading your code or simply intercepting your valid POST requests. **You can validate on the client side for genuine user mistakes, or even for mistakes in your own code, but you should validate on the server side for security and data integrity.**

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you Matt. Data validation is already implemented, but haven't secured the POST requests. Gonna start learning how right now. P.S. I also like your other comment below.

Answer (score 4):

> is this safe?

Depends on what you call safe.

You can never ever trust user input. User can always change the value of 'parent comment'.

You need to make sure that the user is allowed to post a comment with that parent comment on the server side.

Comment: @EJP, from what I understood, op is extracting the parent comment's id from the div's id.

Comment: Yes, which is defined by the HTML rendering mechanism, not by the user.

Comment: You can edit the id of the div for your own instance of the page, and op is most probably extracting the id from that when submitting a comment.

Comment: @EJP: Yes, but the rendering mechanism that sends back HTML from the user to the web server is controlled by the user.

Comment: @EJP: try something like firebug and you ll get why a div id can also be a "user input"

Comment: @EJP - It **is** user input when you send it back to the server. All you need to change it is Firebug.

Answer (score 2):

It seems an exceptionally stupid idea to me to mix display attributes with database attributes. There is no guarantee anywhere that they will always be in sync.

Comment: The ID of this "Add Comment" box I'm about to clicked here on Stack Overflow is "comments-link-6677324", which will be used to send an Ajax request to the back end to add a comment to the answer with that database ID. Just an observation!